How can I make a conditional which tests whether a point in 3d is in front of, or behind a plane?
Edit: I realize that this would be a resource intensive way of accomplishing this task. Perhaps a better way would be to save the coordinates of each little rectangle to a list, and then order them, and them draw them in order - similar  to the pgfplots z buffer. Is this something that can be  done in latex?

How can I make a conditional which tests whether a point in 3d is in front of, or behind a plane?
I can currently test whether they are in front of the screen plane which intersects the origin (in tikz-3dplot), by taking their dot product with the screen-normal-vector. If it is positive, then they are in front of it.
This MWE shows this operation for a wireframe sphere:
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}

\newcommand{\polar}{60}
\newcommand{\azimuth}{45}
\newcommand{\VT}{30}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\polar}{\azimuth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\VT}{\VT}{\VT}
\clip[tdplot_screen_coords] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5);
\draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5);


 % Screen-normal-vector
        \pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirX{\sphereX{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirY{\sphereY{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirZ{\sphereZ{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}}


\fill[white] ({cos(\azimuth)},{sin(\azimuth)}) arc [start angle=\azimuth, end angle={\azimuth-180}, radius=1] -- cycle;
\fill[tdplot_screen_coords,white] ({cos(0)},{sin(0)}) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=1] -- cycle;



\draw[tdplot_screen_coords,ultra thin] ({cos(0)},{sin(0)}) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1]; % outer circle


% longitudinal lines
\foreach \Vnn in {0,10,...,350}{
\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vnn}{0}}{\sphereY{\Vnn}{0}}{\sphereZ{\Vnn}{0}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\tdplotresx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\tdplotresy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\tdplotresz}
\foreach \Vn in {5,10,...,360}{
\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vnn}{\Vn}}{\sphereY{\Vnn}{\Vn}}{\sphereZ{\Vnn}{\Vn}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\tdplotresx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\tdplotresy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vz{\tdplotresz}


        \pgfmathsetmacro\currentDotProduct{\lastx*\viewdirX + \lasty*\viewdirY + \lastz*\viewdirZ} % Dot product with the viewer direction

        % Check if the dot product is positive
           \ifdim\currentDotProduct pt < 0 pt
            \draw[ultra thin,opacity=0.3,blue] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
        \fi
      \ifdim\currentDotProduct pt > -0 pt
            \draw[ultra thin,red] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
        \fi
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\Vz}
\global\let\lastx\lastx
\global\let\lasty\lasty
\global\let\lastz\lastz

} % end inner for loop
} % end outer for loop


% latitudinal lines
\foreach \Vnn in {0,10,...,350}{
\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{0}{\Vnn}}{\sphereY{0}{\Vnn}}{\sphereZ{0}{\Vnn}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\tdplotresx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\tdplotresy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\tdplotresz}
\foreach \Vn in {5,10,...,360}{
\tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vn}{\Vnn}}{\sphereY{\Vn}{\Vnn}}{\sphereZ{\Vn}{\Vnn}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\tdplotresx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\tdplotresy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vz{\tdplotresz}

        \pgfmathsetmacro\currentDotProduct{\lastx*\viewdirX + \lasty*\viewdirY + \lastz*\viewdirZ} % Dot product with the viewer direction

        % Check if the dot product is positive
       \ifdim\currentDotProduct pt < 0 pt
            \draw[ultra thin,opacity=0.3,blue] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
        \fi
      \ifdim\currentDotProduct pt > -0 pt
            \draw[ultra thin,red] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
        \fi
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\Vz}
\global\let\lastx\lastx
\global\let\lasty\lasty
\global\let\lastz\lastz
} % end inner for loop
} % end outer for loop

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


My goal is to draw the example image in Draw Tubular surfaces.
I figured a way to get started would be to draw it sequentially, layer by layer, by testing coordinates through different intervals.
Here is an example where it is done with the screen plane through  the origin:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}
\newcommand{\azimuth}{30}
\newcommand{\polar}{60}
\newcommand{\VT}{10}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\polar}{\azimuth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirX{\sphereX{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}} % Adjusting Z component
\pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirY{\sphereY{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}} % Adjusting Z component
\pgfmathsetmacro\viewdirZ{\sphereZ{-\azimuth}{90 - \polar}} % Adjusting Z component
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0}
\foreach \Vt in {0,10,...,720}{
\draw[ultra thin,variable=\Vtt,domain=90:360,tdplot_rotated_coords] plot ({\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vtt}+4*cos(\Vt)},{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vtt}+4*sin(\Vt)},{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vtt}+5*\Vt/360});
}





\foreach \Vt in {90,100,...,360}{
\draw[ultra thin,variable=\Vtt,domain=0:720,samples=80,tdplot_rotated_coords] plot ({4*cos(\Vtt)+cos(\Vt)*cos(\Vtt)},{4*sin(\Vtt)+cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vtt)},{5*\Vtt/360+sin(\Vt)});
}


\foreach \Vt in {10,20,...,720}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{\sphereX{\Vt-10}{90}+4*cos(\Vt-10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\sphereY{\Vt-10}{90}+4*sin(\Vt-10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lastiz{\sphereZ{\Vt-10}{90}+5*(\Vt-10)/360}

\foreach \Vtt[
    remember=\Vxth as \lastx (initially \lastix),
    remember=\Vyth as \lasty (initially \lastiy),
    remember=\Vzth as \lastz (initially \lastiz),
] in {90,100,...,350}{
% one
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vxo{\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vtt}+4*cos(\Vt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vyo{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vtt}+4*sin(\Vt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vzo{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vtt}+5*\Vt/360}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vxt{\sphereX{\Vt}{\Vtt+10}+4*cos(\Vt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vyt{\sphereY{\Vt}{\Vtt+10}+4*sin(\Vt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vzt{\sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vtt+10}+5*\Vt/360}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vxth{\sphereX{\Vt-10}{\Vtt+10}+4*cos(\Vt-10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vyth{\sphereY{\Vt-10}{\Vtt+10}+4*sin(\Vt-10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Vzth{\sphereZ{\Vt-10}{\Vtt+10}+5*(\Vt-10)/360}


\pgfmathsetmacro\currentDotProduct{\lastx*\viewdirX + \lasty*\viewdirY + \lastz*\viewdirZ} % Dot product with the viewer direction
\ifdim\currentDotProduct pt > 0 pt
% these are the little rectangles
\draw[fill,white,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- ({\Vxo},{\Vyo},{\Vzo}) -- ({\Vxt},{\Vyt},{\Vzt}) -- ({\Vxth},{\Vyth},{\Vzth});
\draw[fill,opacity=0.5,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- ({\Vxo},{\Vyo},{\Vzo}) -- ({\Vxt},{\Vyt},{\Vzt}) -- ({\Vxth},{\Vyth},{\Vzth});
\fi
%\pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vxth}
%\pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vyth}
%\pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\Vzth}
%\global\let\lastx\lastx
%\global\let\lasty\lasty
%\global\let\lastz\lastz

}
\draw[red,thick] ({4*cos(\Vt-10)},{4*sin(\Vt-10)},{5*(\Vt-10)/360}) -- ({4*cos(\Vt)},{4*sin(\Vt)},{5*\Vt/360});
}



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




I'm exploring using something like pythontex to reorder the shaded regions.

This is accomplishable in python, by defining the coordinates for each shaded region, and ordering them with respect to a plane using python syntax. It is also much faster. I'll update this when I get the red line to plot.
import math
import subprocess
import numpy as np

def signed_distance(point, plane_point, normal_vector):
    return np.dot(point - plane_point, normal_vector) / np.linalg.norm(normal_vector)

def sort_rectangles(rectangles, plane_point, normal_vector):
    # Calculate the center of each rectangle for sorting
    distances = []
    for rect in rectangles:
        # Average the coordinates of the rectangle vertices
        center = np.mean(rect, axis=0)
        distance = signed_distance(center, plane_point, normal_vector)
        distances.append((distance, rect))
    # Sort rectangles based on their signed distances
    return [rect for _, rect in sorted(distances)]

def sphereX(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.cos(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereY(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.sin(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereZ(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.sin(math.radians(polar))

viewdirX = sphereX(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirY = sphereY(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirZ = sphereZ(90 - 60, -30)

the_normal_vector = np.array([viewdirX, viewdirY, viewdirZ])

list_of_rectangles = []

for Vt in range(10, 720 + 1, 10):
    current_lastx = sphereX(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lasty = sphereY(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lastz = sphereZ(90, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

    for Vtt in range(90, 350 + 1, 10):
        Vxo = sphereX(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyo = sphereY(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzo = sphereZ(Vtt, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxt = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyt = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzt = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxth = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vyth = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vzth = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

        list_of_rectangles.append([
            (current_lastx, current_lasty, current_lastz),
            (Vxo, Vyo, Vzo),
            (Vxt, Vyt, Vzt),
            (Vxth, Vyth, Vzth)
        ])

        current_lastx = Vxth
        current_lasty = Vyth
        current_lastz = Vzth

# Sort rectangles based on their depth
plane_point = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # Define a plane point (can be adjusted)
sorted_rectangles = sort_rectangles(list_of_rectangles, plane_point, the_normal_vector)

# Write to TeX file
with open("TeX_file.tex", "w") as TeX:
    start = r"""
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
"""
    end = r"""
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
"""
    TeX.write(start)
    for rect in sorted_rectangles:
        # Generate the TeX command for each rectangle
        command = f"""
        \\fill[white] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
        \\fill[opacity=0.5] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
        """
        TeX.write(command)
    TeX.write(end)

subprocess.run(['lualatex', "TeX_file.tex"])



Edit: I collaborated some more with AI, and was able to get it to produce this code, based off my work. I should mention that the original sorting function did come from AI. This is my first time using it to solve a latex problem in some time.
import math
import subprocess
import numpy as np

def signed_distance(point, plane_point, normal_vector):
    return np.dot(point - plane_point, normal_vector) / np.linalg.norm(normal_vector)

def sort_shapes(shapes, plane_point, normal_vector):
    distances = []
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape['type'] == 'rectangle':
            # Average the coordinates of the rectangle vertices
            center = np.mean(shape['vertices'], axis=0)
        elif shape['type'] == 'line':
            # Average the coordinates of the line endpoints
            center = np.mean(shape['endpoints'], axis=0)
        distance = signed_distance(center, plane_point, normal_vector)
        distances.append((distance, shape))
    return [shape for _, shape in sorted(distances)]

def sphereX(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.cos(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereY(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.sin(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereZ(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.sin(math.radians(polar))

viewdirX = sphereX(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirY = sphereY(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirZ = sphereZ(90 - 60, -30)

the_normal_vector = np.array([viewdirX, viewdirY, viewdirZ])

shapes = []

for Vt in range(10, 720 + 1, 10):
    current_lastx = sphereX(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lasty = sphereY(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lastz = sphereZ(90, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

    line_lastx = 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    line_lasty = 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    line_lastz = 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

    for Vtt in range(90, 350 + 1, 10):
        Vxo = sphereX(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyo = sphereY(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzo = sphereZ(Vtt, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxt = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyt = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzt = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxth = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vyth = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vzth = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

        line_nextx = 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        line_nexty = 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        line_nextz = 5 * Vt / 360

        # Add rectangle to shapes
        shapes.append({
            'type': 'rectangle',
            'vertices': [
                (current_lastx, current_lasty, current_lastz),
                (Vxo, Vyo, Vzo),
                (Vxt, Vyt, Vzt),
                (Vxth, Vyth, Vzth)
            ]
        })

        # Add line to shapes
        shapes.append({
            'type': 'line',
            'endpoints': [
                (line_lastx, line_lasty, line_lastz),
                (line_nextx, line_nexty, line_nextz)
            ]
        })

        current_lastx = Vxth
        current_lasty = Vyth
        current_lastz = Vzth

        line_lastx = line_nextx
        line_lasty = line_nexty
        line_lastz = line_nextz

# Sort shapes based on their depth
plane_point = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # Define a plane point (can be adjusted)
sorted_shapes = sort_shapes(shapes, plane_point, the_normal_vector)

# Write to TeX file
with open("TeX_file.tex", "w") as TeX:
    start = r"""
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
"""
    end = r"""
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
"""
    TeX.write(start)
    for shape in sorted_shapes:
        if shape['type'] == 'rectangle':
            rect = shape['vertices']
            command = f"""
            \\fill[white] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
            \\fill[opacity=0.5] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
            """
            TeX.write(command)
        elif shape['type'] == 'line':
            line = shape['endpoints']
            command = f"""
            \\draw[black] ({line[0][0]},{line[0][1]},{line[0][2]}) -- ({line[1][0]},{line[1][1]},{line[1][2]});
            """
            TeX.write(command)
    TeX.write(end)

subprocess.run(['lualatex', "TeX_file.tex"])


